# Action method not working OSX

Tags: swift, macos

I am trying to handle a click event if the user presses on a textfield. Somehow it is not jumping inside the function. Here is my code:

```
class ViewController: NSViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {

        let textField2 = NSTextField(frame: CGRectMake(30, 30, 37, 17))
        textField2.stringValue = "Label"
        textField2.bordered = false
        textField2.backgroundColor = NSColor.controlColor()
        view.addSubview(textField2)

        textField2.action = #selector(myAction)
    }

    func myAction(sender: NSView)
    {
        print("aktuell: \(sender)")
        currentObject = sender
    }
}
```

If I click on the textfield it is not jumping inside the function.
Does anybody know how to link the textfield to the function? Please note that it has to be that function because I am linking other controls to it as well (e.g. buttons).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't link a text field like that.  What is it you're trying to accomplish?  You probably want the NSTextFieldDelegate methods instead.  Look at the help on that protocol.  If those have what you want, then just set `textField2.delegate = self` and then implement the protocol.

Comment: Yes can I link all textfields to one single method?

Comment: I also have to get an instance of the textfield like the sender in the action method.

Comment: Yes.  If you look at the delegate methods you'll notice their first parameter is always the textField that has the action being taken.  So you don't reference  your text field variable you created, you use the one passed into the delegate method.

Comment: Ok, I implemented the NSTextFieldDelegate and set the delegate to self. But I can't find a function if the current textfield is tapped (got focus). Tried it with textShouldBeginEditing (function of NSTextFieldDelegate) but this function is invoked if the user tries to enter something. I need a function if the textfield got the focus. Do you know how solve this?

Comment: I think you need to ask yourself why you really need to know that.  If you do though, you'll have to subclass NSTextField and override the becomeFirstResponder() function.  Then you'll know when you become the first responder.  Be sure you call super!

Answer (score 0):

Implement - (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField method of UITextFieldDelegate protocol. For example:

```
 - (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
if textField.isEqual(firstTextField){
//some code
}
if textField.isEqual(secondTextField){
//other code
}
}
```

Comment: @Anokrize Oh, sorry for that. Try this instead:  
control(_:textShouldBeginEditing:)

Comment: Link to docs: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSControlTextEditingDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/NSControlTextEditingDelegate